# In Excell- Its possible to populate data based on other cell value without using VBA?

Tags: excel

I have the following

[image: excell example]

I tried to go with If / Else but the references changed. I'm not figuring out.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the VLOOKUP function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward case to use `VLOOKUP()`.  In `C2`, put this and drag down:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,$F$2:$G$4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: THANKS! I use my excell on portuguese, then was:
=PROCV($A2;$F$2:$G$4;2;FALSO)

Comment: @ContatoNewFaceFotos - if this worked, you can mark as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post (below the up/down arrows).